# react hook for multiple component state didn't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a hook, and 2 components. Component App.js has a function that changes the state in hook, but the value is not updated in Component New.js, why? I think I've missed something but can't figure it out.

App.js

```
export const useToggle = () => {
  const [onOff, setOnOff] = useState(false);
  return [onOff, () => setOnOff((prev) => !prev)];
};

export default function App() {
  const [onOff, setOnOff] = useToggle();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{onOff.toString()}</h1>
      <button onClick={setOnOff}>toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

New.js

```
import { useToggle } from "./App.js";

export default function New() {
  const [onOff] = useToggle();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <hr />
      <h1>NEW:</h1>
      <pre>{onOff.toString()}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-fire-rjude?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `useToggle` hook is its own entity with its own state. The `useToggle` that you are toggling in `App` isn't the same `useToggle` that is rendered/used in `New`.

This means they are toggled independently of any other hooks and state. They don't share "state".

If you are wanting to create a `useToggle` hook that does have shared state then I would suggest implementing it via a React context and the `useContext` hook so each `useToggle` hook can toggle the same shared state held in the context.

#### Update

Global `useToggle` hook.

togglecontext.js

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

export const ToggleContext = createContext([false, () => {}]);

const ToggleProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [onOff, setOnOff] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setOnOff(t => !t);

  return (
    <ToggleContext.Provider value={[onOff, toggle]}>
      {children}
    </ToggleContext.Provider>
  );
}

export const useToggle = () => useContext(ToggleContext);

export default ToggleProvider;
```

index - provide the context

```
...
import ToggleProvider from "./toggle.context";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <ToggleProvider>
      <App />
      <New />
    </ToggleProvider>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

App

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useToggle } from "./toggle.context";

export default function App() {
  const [onOff, setOnOff] = useToggle();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{onOff.toString()}</h1>
      <button onClick={setOnOff}>toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

New

```
import { useToggle } from "./toggle.context";

export default function New() {
  const [onOff] = useToggle();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <hr />
      <h1>NEW:</h1>
      <pre>{onOff.toString()}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-hook-for-multiple-component-state-didnt-update]

Note that the only thing that changed in the `App` and `New` components was the import, where the `useToggle` hook is defined.

Comment: how to make it share then?

Comment: @alice_morgan I must've read your mind as I was just adding that to my answer. Do you need an example demonstration?

Comment: I wonder why I need to use context, I just want to share changed state with other components, isn't that hook is for? I know useContext is for inner children to get state from multiple component, but in my case I only have 2 components, why do I need to use context?

Comment: @alice_morgan No, hooks serve several different purposes, solve different use cases.

Comment: @alice_morgan "I wonder why I need to use context" It's a design pattern React has available so you don't need to explicitly pass state and callback functions to update the state as props down through all your react components to the components that actually care about them. You could certainly [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the parent, but then you lose out on the encapsulated code of the `useToggle` hook, you'd need to pass `onOff` and a `toggleOnOff` function to both child components.

Comment: you used context, replaced my hook, I think I need that hook

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237202/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-alice-morgan).

Comment: @alice_morgan Just an FYI, I tried answering your last comments in the chat. I'm not sure I follow your question "what is the solution before `useContext`" though. Can you clarify that?

Comment: I think I'll ditch custom hook and use context.

Comment: @alice_morgan The Context API and hooks each serve a different purpose, but work well together. It's not uncommon to also export a custom hook for any exported contexts and providers. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I got confused with 2 of them. In your experience, in what circumstances you'll use hook over context? is it right to say 'to share state between multiple components, use context'? but isn't hook also allow that? just that hook doesn't work if the states would need to pass to children components?

Comment: @alice_morgan Responded in chat.